# Mongoose Populated Document not visible in MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have put together a reference model, a profile has one user (logon user). I am able to associate the User to the Profile when I create the user by passing in the User ObjectId.

Then, when I "populate" the Collection on the reference field (e.g. userRef), MongoDB Compass does not show the document. MongoDB Compass still shows the User ObjectID template type.

However, I can access the reference object from vsCode. For example, I log out the value of Profile.userRef on the instance of the Profile model, it returns the correct UserRef doc. It is just not visible in Compass...

Anyone come across this before?

```html
db.ProfileModel.findOne({ profileType: "Cadet" })
  .populate({
    path: "userRef",
    model: "User",
  })
  .exec(function (err, profile) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(profile.userRef);
  });
```

Comment: How are you "populating" on MongoDB Compass?

Comment: inserted some code above. as I mentioned, when I log the profile.userRef, the correct user is logged, but when I go into compass, it still shows as an ObjectID.

Comment: Mongoose uses two queries to fulfill the request (populate). Compass is showing you how in reality you documents looks like.

Comment: based on your comment, appears the code is correctly configured? Compass just shows a different view. But the UserRef info could still be available in the app.